# Race condition in django session

Tags: django, session, django-rest-framework

I have an API using django that uses session:

```
def api_a(request):
  request.session["foo1"] = "bar1"
  return Response({})

def api_b(request):
  request.session["foo2"] = "bar2"
  return Response({})
```

If I call `api_a` **THEN** `api_b`, `request.session` is set to `{foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2}`, and that's the expected behavior.

However, if I call simultaneously `api_a` and `api_b` (the calls are performed by a JavaScript front), it seems that when each call begins, `request.session` is empty, and each call saves the session with only one element, resulting `request.session` set to `{foo1: bar1}` (`foo2` is missing) (or viceversa).

Is there a way to change session behavior to resolve this race condition ?

*Note: session is configured with Redis (but I'm not sure it's relevant) :*

```
CACHES = {"default": {"BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",}}
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

Comment: Difficult to "answer" since it depends on what you are trying to do.  With the default cache backend the entire session is a single object, so this is unavoidable.  A new strategy is needed.  Perhaps save individual keys outside the "session" object using redis, or a custom session backend which implements the new behavior?

Comment: That's the current plan. But then, it should be mentioned, and warned somewhere that session is prone to race condition and should be used only for one key. (imagine an online shop with `request.session[item]=amount`, it will litteraly be broken)